# Is it more correct to say "repeat", or "resay"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar, word-usage

Telling a person to repeat something they have said sounds better to me, but is it more correct to ask them to resay what they said?

If I say something then resay it, then I have said it again. I don't peat, so why would I repeat? Do I peat? What does peat mean when referred to this way?

Which is better, repeat or resay?

Comment: I don't believe I've ever heard or read *resay*. Funky to see definitions for it across the web, though reassuring to learn that it doesn't exist in many other. And my spell checkers all seem to disapprove.

Comment: Pete and Re-Pete were in a boat. Pete fell out; who was left?

Comment: "Could you say that again, please?  I didn't quite get it the first time."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, "repeat" doesn't actually have a prefix. So, you aren't "peating" something again.
 It's a word derived from [French:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=repeat&searchmode=none)

> repeat
>   late 14c., from O.Fr. repeter "say or do again, get back, demand the return of" (13c.), from L. repetere "do or say again, attack again," from re- "again" + petere "go toward, seek, demand, attack" (see petition). Specific meaning "to take a course of education over again" is recorded from 1945, Amer.Eng. Related: Repeated; repeating. The noun is first recorded 1550s.

It has a prefix in Latin, but not in English.

As you can see, "repeat" can mean 'to do or say again', so "repeat" can be used to mean to 'resay'.

Interestingly, [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=resay&searchmode=none) and [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/resay) both don't give records of 'resay'.

Answer (score 6):

FWIW, in the Army, we were taught that if a radio transmission was unclear, then to say, **"say again"** ... NEVER repeat. Repeat has a specific meaning, it means to fire again. Thus if you're talking to an artillery unit and say "repeat" over the radio, they will fire again.

While [***resay***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/resay) does exist, it is better to say, "say again".

If skaldic muses are pushing you to write poetry, you could always use the [seldseen](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/seldseen) (rare) prefixes of *ed-* (= re-) or *agen-* (= re-, again) ... [agenbite](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/agenbite) = remorse.

However, for talking, use "say again".

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. I was looking forward to explaining, but you beat me to it.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

If I didn't quite hear what you said (not loud enough, indistinct, etc.), I would ask you to **repeat**.  If I heard every word you said, but I didn't understand what you meant, I would ask you to **restate** what you said; "resay" doesn't sound felicitous to me.

In English, of course, we generally just say "What?" in either case.  In Spanish you could say "*¿Qué?*" ("What?") if you didn't hear, or "*¿Cómo?*" ("How?") if you didn't understand; in Russian it's the same: "*Что?*" or "*Как?*"  I wish we had a similar convention in English conversation...

Answer (score 1):

or use [Reiterate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reiterate)

Which means 'say again'

Answer (score 0):

There is an entry for "resay" in Merriam-Webster:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resay

No example sentences are provided however.

Google Books documents only a handful of written mentions.